# Mask email address, phonenumber, ssn (pattern) using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, cat

Requirement is to mask some sensitive data from the log file, below code works as expected when `awk` version is **4.0.2**.

I will be `grep`ing the log files and then have to mask some data using pattern as mentioned in the below `awk` snippet and then return the result.

```
echo "123-123-432-123-999-889 and 123456 and 1234-1234-4321-1234 and xyz@abc.com" | awk ' gsub (/[0-9]{6,}|([0-9]{3,}.){3,}|\w{2,}@\w{2,}.\w{2,}/, "****") 1'
```

The same is not working in `awk` version **3.1.7** which is production server version.

I can use only `grep, cat, awk` and there is **no permission to use `perl` or `sed`** as it is restricted by Admin Team.

**Expected Output:**

```
****and **** and ****and ****
```

Solution should also work if the content is in file, for example

### **sample.log**

```
123-123-432-123-999-889
and 
123456
and
1234-1234-4321-1234 
and xyz@abc.com
```

**Command:**

```
 cat sample.log  | awk ' gsub (/[0-9]{6,}|([0-9]{3,}.){3,}|\w{2,}@\w{2,}.\w{2,}/, "****") 1'
```

Please help me with awk which can work in **3.1.7** version of `awk`

Comment: Why is sed restricted?

Comment: Logs are in production server and we dont have permission to commands which can directly alter the files over there.

Comment: But awk can.... Why not just correctly set the permissions. If you have write access you could just do `>file`. Banning commands is ridiculous.

Comment: @123, By the way, logs are created by different user and we have only read access to that files. and yes I'm aware of these workaounds works if we have write permission, but our admin might be thinking we are not aware of it.
They have restricted commands 'touch', but > (redirection) creates a file :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate RE intervals with:

```
awk --re-interval '...'
```

You MAY also need to replace `\w`s with `[[:alnum:]_]`.

The problem you;re having is that you're using a very old version of gawk from before RE Intervals (e.g. `{1,3}`) were enabled by default so in that old gawk every `{` and `}` is just a literal character for backward compatibility with the 1980s awks (old, broken awk and nawk), so you need to explicitly tell gawk to interpret `{1,3}` as a RE Interval instead of a literal string of 5 chars.

Idk if back then `\w` was supported or not so you MAY also need to use the bracket expression I suggested above instead.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you it worked out by adding --re-interval without replacing \w